# Circular lists in Racket

Tags: list, racket

It has been a while since i last programmed in Racket.
Now i wanted to make a circular list in Racket as follows :

```
(define x (list 1 2))
(set-mcdr! (cdr x) x)
```

But this gives rises to the error :

```
set-mcdr!: contract violation
expected: mpair?
given: '(2)
argument position: 1st
other arguments...:
 '(1 2)
```

I'm surprised because `(cddr x)` is `'()` so I don't understand why he tells me "expected: mpair?" as `'(2)` is a pair (with `cdr` the empty list).

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The list must be *mutable* if you want `set-mcdr!` to work, and all procedures used must also operate on mutable pairs; please check the [documentation](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/mpairs.html) and notice that all the procedures contain an `m` as part of their name. For example, try this:

```
(require racket/mpair)

(define x (mlist 1 2))
(set-mcdr! (mcdr x) x)
```

Comment: The full documentation for [`racket/mpair`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/compatibility/mlists.html?q=mpair). It's buried under `Legacy Languages and Libraries -> Compatibility: Features from Racket Relatives -> 3 Mutable List Functions` from the Racket Documentation index.

Answer (score 2):

Other answers are of course entirely correct. I'd like to add, though, that there might be a different data structure that serves your needs better! I would take a look at `in-cycle`:

```
#lang racket

(define cyclic-sequence 
  (in-cycle (list 3 4 5)))

(for/list ([elt cyclic-sequence]
           [i (in-range 13)])
  elt)
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you worked with Racket they introduced immutable pairs as standard. That means you cannot set `car` or `cdr` unless it's contructed of `mcons`.

However, in the SRFI-1 there is a constructor that makes circular lists and makes the list compatible with all procedures in #!racket that expects immutable lists:

```scm
#!racket

(require srfi/1)
(circular-list 1 2 3) ; ==> #0=(1 2 3 . #0#)

;; alternatively you can make a list circular
(apply circular-list '(1 2 3)) ; ==> #0=(1 2 3 . #0#)

(map cons '(1 2 3 4 5 6) (circular-list #t)) 
; ==> ((1 . #t) (2 . #t) (3 . #t) (4 . #t) (5 . #t) (6 . #t))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Racket's built in functions for creating [immutable cyclic data structures](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28part._.Immutable_.Cyclic_.Data%29) (This is what the Racket implementation of SRFI-1 `circular-list` uses internally). For example:

```
#lang racket/base

(define (make-circular-list . elems)
  (define ph (make-placeholder #f))
  (define circular-list (append elems ph))
  (placeholder-set! ph circular-list)
  (make-reader-graph circular-list))

(define x (make-circular-list 1 2)) ; x is written #0='(1 2 . #0#)

(require racket/list) ; for take
(println (take x 5)) ; '(1 2 1 2 1)
```